# Не могу установить pyqiwip2p, может кто сталкивался?

Tags: python

Снова здорова, в общем следующая проблема, пишу код бота для ТГ, мини магазин, и нужно прикрутить киви, как я понял читая документации нужно поставить библиотеку pyqiwip2p, проблема в том, что она попросту не устанавливается.... Я уже код на половину написал, может больше, но понял поздно что библиотека не воткнулась, выдавала сначала подобную проблему "ignoring invalid distribution c python36 lib site-packages", почитал форумы, пришел к выводу что нужно удалить папки в site-packages которые имеют ~ в названии. Удалил такие папки, и теперь просто нет желтых и красных строк ошибок при установке библиотеки, но она так и не втыкается как понял. Ведь строчка "from pyqiwip2p.types import QiwiCustomer, QiwiDatetime" по прежнему выдает ошибку в терминале "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqiwip2p.types'", в общем сижу без настроения уже 2ые сутки, и не могу понять как разобраться... облазил весь интернет, надежда только на вас, вы как последняя инстанция.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyqiwip2p.p2p_types import QiwiCustomer, QiwiDatetime
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).